I am unable to run the command poetry install --extras ui,local
whenever I am running this I am getting the local not found in extras error.
I tried to run "poetry install --extras "ui vector-stores-qdrant llms-ollama embeddings-huggingface". But unable to run it.
I am trying to run the privateGPT locally. But unable to do it help me with it.
